Avoid pnpm symlinking specific packages in monorepo
I'm working with a pretty large monorepo (turborepo) and use pnpm as a package manager. Does anyone know of a way to tell pnpm to just install a specific package from that monorepo into other packages in the same monorepo using the same approach that npm would, without symlinking or hoisting the package to the root node_modules directory? One of the packages needs to modify it's own content, kind of similar to what Prisma does based on content in the other packages. Symlinking just results in the modifications being applied to the main package, and hoisting would result in the changes for all of the packages being applied at once. This is my .npmrc:
hoist-workspace-packages=true
public-hoist-pattern[]=*prisma*
public-hoist-pattern[]=!api
public-hoist-pattern[]=!@ulld/api
hoist-pattern[]=!api
hoist-pattern[]=!@ulld/api
auto-install-peers=true
legacy-peer-deps=true
node-linker=hoisted
symlink=false

